# Cannot interact with public Instagram user feed

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm working on a small project for a friend and I'm running into issues with their instagram feed.  I'm using an Instagram widget, when I put their username in, it returns nothing.  I've ensured the account is not set to private and it shows up when searching and on the website.  http://instagram.com/pantylanddiary.

When I input my username or anyone else's it works just fine.  Any clue where I can start in troubleshooting this?

I've even authorized an app in Instagram called iconosquare for stats and their widget will not show the feed in question and will show my feed just fine.

Comment: This is just a guess, but Instagram does filter out tags related to adult content. For example, it will not return results for the hashtag "#panty". I'm wondering if the string "panty" in the username is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Bill.  I'll investigate that.  That makes total sense...